# What is the return value of shared_ptr<T>::get() after it is released?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

After releasing a `std::shared_ptr<T>`, when I do `ptr.get()` is the return value `NULL` or `nullptr`? In order to compare, I used this:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> ptr(new int(44));

ptr.reset();
int *p = ptr.get();

if (p == nullptr)
{
    cout << "nullptr";
}

if (p == NULL)
{
    cout << "NULL";
}
```

Both seem to be the result.

Comment: Your test is incomplete without `if (nullptr == NULL) {cout << "They are the same!" << endl; }` line :):):)

Comment: Another thing you might not know is that `shared_ptr` has an implicit cast to `bool` that is basically equivalent to `p != nullptr`. So you can write `p == nullptr` *or* `!p` - whichever is more intuitive to you.

Comment: The value of `ptr.get()` is the null `int*` value (rather than the null `nullptr_t` value or a `0` integral value), so the following would be closer `typedef int* intp; if (p == intp{}) { std::cout << "intp{}"; }`. That said, all of the above are implicitly convertible/comparable to each other, so it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C++11, use `nullptr`.

It is true that they are both correct and equivalent in this case, since both are *null pointer constants* as specified by paragraph 4.10/1 (`NULL` is usually `#define`d to be `0`):

> A *null pointer constant* is an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to
>   zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the
>   result is the *null pointer value* of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or
>   function pointer type.

However, `nullptr` is recognized by the type system as **the** pointer literal of type `nullptr_t` and as a special null pointer constant, so its semantics are clear both to you and to the compiler. `NULL`, on the other hand, is just a macro that is known to expand to zero.

Answer (score 2):

> ***2.14.7 Pointer literals [lex.nullptr]***
>
> The pointer literal is the keyword nullptr. It is a prvalue of type
> std::nullptr_t. [ Note: std::nullptr_t is a distinct type that is
> neither a pointer type nor a pointer to member type; rather, a prvalue
> of this type is a null pointer constant and can be converted to a null
> pointer value or null member pointer value.

Both are equivalent, but you should prefer to use nullptr.